# What is wrong with this simple F# block?

Tags: f#

I have a test in C# that looks like this:

```
public void CanLog()
{
    ModUnderTest.Log.Info("HI");
}
```

This C# code throws a Null Reference exception saying that `ModUnderTest.Log` is null in the test. Here is the code under test:

```
module ModUnderTest
    let Log = log4net.LogManager.GetLogger("name")
```

Why does this not work? It compiles fine but fails at runtime.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

My guess is either (1) `GetLogger` is returning null (you have the wrong 'name'), or (2) the F# code is in an EXE rather than a DLL, and the static initializer for the module is not being run.